# Entity manager's delete child is not detaching child from parent

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a parent entity and a one to many reference of `Set<Child>` in this parent entity… 
on using entity manager's(being injected in my `DAO` as say "em") delete as `em.delete(child)` is not deleting its reference from my parent's list…

like after debugging `parent.getChildren()`, I can still find that child that has been deleted in the parent's children list…

How do i detach this child from parent's list??

Comment: Please share the code for entities and DAO layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected. Deleting an entity only markes it as removed, and causes the next flush to delete the corresponding row in the database. If you open a new session and reload the parent entity, the child won't be in the set anymore. If you want the child to be removed from the set immediately, then it's your responsibility to do it:

```
parent.getChildren().remove(child);
```